# Why does V8 using a temporary variable to swap two values outperform implementations with no temporary variable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

This [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/swap-two-numbers-without-tmp-var/17) test says that using a temporary variable `c` to swap two values `a` and `b` vastly outperforms an alternative implementation using only the two variables and bitwise operations in V8.

[image]

Fastest: `c = b; b = a; a = c;`

Slowest: `a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b;`

I understand that scripting languages do not have the optimizations one would expect from compiled languages, but assuming that `a` and `b` are integers, why would bitwise operations perform so poorly in Chrome's V8? Why are these results the way they are?

Comment: Different browsers have different JS engines which will perform dramatically different in situations like these. I just ran them in Safari, which, as I'd expect, behaves quite differently from Chrome. Check it out at http://jsperf.com/swap-two-numbers-without-tmp-var/17

Comment: Since when does the xor operator "swap" the variables in the same way as the first example ?

Comment: @adeneo Since I assumed use of integers for the sake of this question.

Comment: It still doesn't really swap them, it reverses the bits in an "exclusive or" pattern, and one could generally expect that to take longer than just creating a new variable with a primitive value

Comment: So, first roughly looks like 3 load operations followed by 3 store operations, while the second is 6 loads, 3 xors and 3 stores. Why it should be faster then?

Comment: actually, these days, scripting languages have WAY MORE optimizations than compiled languages, because they have a lot more input available to them to make decisions than something that has to be figured out before the user does anything, the amount of free ram is known, the usage of certain libs has been traced, etc...

Comment: If any of you have answers, please put them in the answers section along with any corrections you feel assists the community. I'm at work and wasn't planning on maintaining a conversation.

Comment: @dandavis "scripting languages have WAY MORE optimizations than compiled languages" --- dynamically typed languages don't have that much information that statically typed compiled languages, so that does not sound true at all.

Comment: ex: V8 knows that you click on one button more than another button, c++ apps don't. look at techs like FF's tracing, chakra's background compilation, how often V8's optimistic assumptions pan true, etc. most JS is executed JIT-compiled anyway, so most of the traditional early optimizations _can_ still apply to JS as well, along with a whole class of late optimizations unavailable to compiled code. in short the days of IE6 predictable interpreter perf are long over because of optimizations.

Comment: @dandavis that's correct - it can perform some known optimisations in runtime as soon as some conditions stay true. It also can deoptimise a chunk of code. It also means it cannot perform some advanced optimisations that gcc and clang do for years. I'm not sure if you're referring to the quantity or the *quality* of optimisations, but the latter is far from being comparable with mature C++ compilers.

Comment: @zerkms: good points. it's an ongoing evolution with the gap constantly closing. i was mainly objecting to the characterization that "scripting" cannot optimize simple code patterns like demo'd by OP...

Comment: Testing in Chrome 48.0.2564.97 on Mac OS X 10.11.3 : Using temporary var gets better results.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of observations:

- XOR-swap is slower in almost any language, on any contemporary hardware. Auxiliary variables are mostly free.
- In a nice language, the first version does 3 reads and 3 writes. The XOR-version performs 6 reads, 3 XOR operations, 3 writes. Moreover, the XOR-ing defeats various additional downstream analyses that a decent compiler can trivially do on the former version.
- In JavaScript, the XOR-version in fact performs 6 reads, 6 or more type comparisons, up to 6 unboxings, 6 ToInt32 conversions, 3 XOR operations, up to 3 boxings (including heap allocations), 3 writes. And that's assuming the original values are already numbers. With enough warm-up and type profiling, a modern JS VM like V8 can optimise and avoid many of these, but obviously can't ever get better than the first version.
- Microbenchmarks are vastly misleading when it comes to performance, especially for a language with as complex and flaky runtime characteristics as JavaScript. Don't put too much trust in tools like JSPerf.
- It is highly unlikely that this ever makes an observable performance difference in any real JavaScript program, so why do you care?

Comment: > "It is highly unlikely that this ever makes an observable performance difference in any real JavaScript program, so why do you care?"

Curiosity